# map issues with objects js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, mapping

The below piece of code angular does not indexing properly it keeps data from previous objects for some reason. The issue it comes there. I want to map the objects from a list of objects and update their index.

```
for (let i of this.arrayofObjects) {
        lobby.list.map(function (item: Model, index: number) {
            item.position = index + 1;
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data of `this.arrayOfObjects` so that we can help further?

Comment: this.arrayOfObjects belongs into a Model so please see below:  export class Model { id: number; arrayOfObjects: Array<Model2>} export class Model2 {id:number;type:string; position:number;   constructor (id: number, type: string, position:id) as you can see are two different models did that help?

Comment: a jsfiddle link will help others to understand your issue